# Is there any evidence of Bitcoin being "Tainted"?

Tags: privacy, security, cryptocurrency-comparison, bitcoin

Monero claims to be fungible, meaning every XMR is worth the same as another XMR. But I've also people say this isn't true about Bitcoin - and that Bitcoin can be tainted.

Is there any evidence of some Bitcoin being valued at a different price, or any evidence of some Bitcoin being treated differently based on it's past?

Comment: This already has an answer on the relevant (bitcoin) SE site: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/what-are-tainted-coins-exactly and a casual search yields endless articles: https://www.google.com/?q=what%20are%20virgin%20bitcoin Every bitcoin is tainted as every bitcoin has a public history.

Answer (score 3):

**2021 Edit**: The following website has significantly more examples: https://blog.sethforprivacy.com/posts/fungibility-graveyard/

Old answer below:

---

A few examples of Tainted/Clean Bitcoins come to mind:

Binance blocking a mixed BTC deposit: https://blockonomi.com/binance-blocks-bitcoin-withdrawal-wasabi-wallet/

Bitcoins requiring a history audit: https://redd.it/8tzh7w

Bitcoin node dropping transactions from BTC used in gambling: https://bugs.gentoo.org/524512

Dirty BTC on the Bisq market: https://bisq.community/t/dirty-btc-coins-on-the-xmr-market/7798

Chinese police freezing bank accounts that traded tainted BTC on OTC market: https://www.coindesk.com/china-police-freeze-otc-traders-bank-accounts-tainted-crypto

FBI document mentions DNM users discussing how to "clean" "dirty" BTC: https://ia803206.us.archive.org/23/items/dark-web-files-from-blueleaks/200309%20LES%20FBI%20EIR%20-%20Darknet%20Market%20Actors%20Likely%20Convert%20Illicit%20Bitcoin%20to%20Monero%20Using%20MorphToken%20Cryptocurrency%20Exchange%2C%20Impeding%20Law%20Enforcement%20Tracing%20Efforts.pdf